# Summarising by non-spatial dimension prevents removal of undissolved specks

Tags: r, dplyr, geospatial, r-sf

[This shape](https://pastebin.com/yWCWg2DV) retains residual specks or crumbs after dissolving inner boundaries. Package `rmapshaper` is not able to remove the specks when a non-spatial dimension (time) is included in the dissolving/aggregating process. Can the specks be removed (with or without `rmapshaper`), hopefully without dissolving and aggregating separately then merging the results?

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(rmapshaper)

#download file "shape.txt" from Pastebin link above
shape <- dget("shape.txt")

class(shape)
[1] "sf"         "data.frame"

plot(shape$geometry)
```

[image]

```
#aggregate with year
shape1 <- shape %>% group_by(a1, year) %>% summarise(count=sum(count)) %>% ungroup()
#aggregate without year
shape2 <- shape %>% group_by(a1) %>% summarise(count=sum(count)) %>% ungroup()

#results contain specks
plot(shape1$geometry)
plot(shape2$geometry)
```

[image]

```
#remove specks: unsuccessful
shape1 <- ms_filter_islands(shape1, min_area=1000000)
plot(shape1$geometry)

#remove specks: successful
shape2 <- ms_filter_islands(shape2, min_area=1000000)
plot(shape2$geometry)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all: the grouping by year in your example does not *feel* right. The areas look like administrative units, and you end up with two summarised polygons drawn on top of each other.

In an ideal world I would probably separate the geometry object from the yearly data.

But having said this I will treat your example as a toy example, meant to demonstrate a problem rather than to make a sense by itself.

Consider this code: as the specks are tiny it is possible to remove them (or rather avoid creating them in the first place) by buffering your original polygons by 10 units and then unbuffering the final polygon by the same amount.

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

#download file "shape.txt" from Pastebin link above
shape <- dget("shape.txt")

# buffer & unbuffer
shape2 <- shape %>% 
  st_buffer(10) %>% # first create a small buffer ...
  group_by(a1, year) %>% 
  summarise(count=sum(count)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  st_buffer(-10) # ... and then remove it to preserve area

plot(shape2$geometry)
```

[image]

You will end up with two polygons drawn on top of each other, with no specks.

Comment: You are correct that this is a toy example. I should have selected a single year in the `plot` instructions. That being said, it seemed more parsimonious to me to store shapes and years in the same table rather than separately, to avoid having to merge every time before plotting. Is that also unorthodox?

Comment: @syre - perhaps I should have written unexpected; I meant no offense, and I don't claim any holy grail of orthodoxy. I hope the buffer approach resolves your issues / which is what matters...

Comment: @Jindra_Lacko No offense taken; just looking to learn about proper data structuring as well. So I should have written *suboptimal* rather than *unorthodox* :)